# Series using comparison test

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

The series is as shown
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{\tan(1/n)}{n^{0.5}}$$

Using P-series, 0.5<1 therefore it is divergent
$$\frac{1}{n^{0.5}}$$

It appears that i can't use P-series

What test should i use if this is wrong as it should converge rather than diverge

Answer (score 0):

Don't be too hasty! For large $n$, $\tan(1/n) \sim 1/n$, where $\sim$ means that the two are asymptotic as $n$ approaches $\infty$. As $n$ increases, your whole summand is asymptotic to $1/n^{(3/2)}$. I think your series actually converges.

This is a heuristic argument, though it could probably pass in a Calc 2 course.

Comment: what test should i use as i am unable to proceed. The answer is converge but P-series test fails.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test

Use the limit comparison test.

Comment: if i were to use limit comparison test, what would the numerator be since the denominator would be $$\frac{1}{n^{0.5}}$$

Comment: Compare your current summand to $1/n^{(3/2)}$.

Comment: by limit comparison test, won't it cancel leaving behind only $$\tan(\frac{1}{n})$$

Comment: No, it will leave $n \tan(1/n)$. You can show that this limit is equal to $1$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. Substitute $n = 1/x$ and use L'Hopital's rule.

Comment: $$\frac{\tan(1/n)}{n^{(1/2)}} / \frac{1}{n^{(3/2)}}$$

Comment: something i can't figure out is how did you get the 3/2  as i thought for limit comparison, i am supposed to take the highest power affecting the numerator and denominator based on the series itself thus i came up with 1/2

Comment: I use ${1}/{n^{(3/2)}}$ because I know $$ \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\tan(x)}{x} = 1,$$
or in terms of $n$,
$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n \tan(1/n) = 1.$$
You may not have encountered it before, but as $x$ goes to $0$, $\sin(x)$ gets very close to $x$. We call this relationship "asymptotic." Because $\tan = \sin / \cos$, and I know $\cos$ approaches $1$ as $x \rightarrow 0$, then I can also say that $\tan(x)$ will get very close to $x$ as $x$ gets small.

Comment: Here's a graph which show what I was talking about:
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=graph+of+tan+x%2C+graph+of+x